# Initial value for dateTextField (Apache Wicket)

Tags: java, apache, wicket

Iv'e been trying to add a dateTextField to a legacy code for a project i'm working on, and I did not succeed to init the value of it to empty (as initial value).

I found some examples for dateTime, but not for dateTextField, and would like to get some help with that; this is the code:

```
    DateTextField dateTextField = new DateTextField("dateTextField", new PropertyModel<Date>(
            this, "date"), new StyleDateConverter("S-", true))
    {
        @Override
        public Locale getLocale()
        {
            return selectedLocale;
        }
    };

    form.add(dateTextField);

    DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker()
    {
        @Override
        protected String getAdditionalJavaScript()
        {
            return "${calendar}.cfg.setProperty(\"navigator\",true,false); ${calendar}.render();";
        }
    };

    datePicker.setShowOnFieldClick(true);
    datePicker.setAutoHide(true);
    dateTextField.add(datePicker);
```

and the markup:

```
<input type="text" wicket:id="dateTextField" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer eventually:

```
    DateTextField dateTextField =new DateTextField("dateTextField", new Model<Date>(null), new DayMonthDateConverter(false));
    dateTextField.add(datePicker);
    form.add(dateTextField);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
DateTextField dateTextField = new DateTextField("dateTextField", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
form.addOrReplace(dateTextField.add(new DatePicker()).setVisible(true));
```